# Title "not centered" when the report is being run using excel 2007

Tags: cognos, cognos-8

I'm working on an existing cognos report where a user specifically asked me to make changes. When the user runs the report, they run it in excel. When the user downloads the report  to excel the title isn't centered. This threw me off because when viewing my report in Cognos Report Studio, the title is centered. What is the cause of this and is there a fix? They seek this change so they don't have to manually make the changes in excel before putting it to their use.

**EDIT:**

Report studio:

[image]

Excel:

[image]

When I run the report in HTML or PDF the title is perfectly in the middle, only excel renders it off.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

IBM Cognos has limitations when producing reports in Microsoft Excel format.

One work around for this problem is to use include the report title text in a table cell in the Page header block. Given below are the steps.

1. Insert a table of 1 column and 1 row (i.e. 1 table cell) in the Page header block.
2. Add "Text Item" in the table cell.
3. Give appropriate report title in that text item.
4. Select the table cell; In the 'Font & Text' properties, specify the horizontal alignment property to be 'Center'.
5. Run the report in Excel 2007 format.

This also works for Excel 2002 format.

You can find some of the limitations for Excel format here:

[Unsupported Excel Formatting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_rptstd_fin.8.4.0.doc/ug_rptstd_fin_id4744UnsupportedExcelFormatting.html)

[Unsupported IBM Cognos 8 Formatting](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_rptstd_fin.8.4.0.doc/ug_rptstd_fin_id4621excel_appendx_unsupp_formatting.html)

[Limitations When Producing Reports in Microsoft Excel Format](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/c8bi/v8r4m0/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.swg.im.cognos.ug_rptstd_fin.8.4.0.doc/ug_rptstd_fin_id4565excel_limitations.html)

@MichaelYounani 
Instead of having title texts (6 rows) in 2 different table structures, you can move all the 6 rows of title in the same table. 
Please refer to the screen shot.

[image: Align Table cells in report studio]

That way, when the report is run in Excel format, you can get all the title rows in one column and aligned to the center. 
[image: After Aligned]

Comment: I tried centering it as well, but it did not work for me. Seems like such a simple issue, but I jus cant jot it down.

Comment: @MichaelYounani  When I put the text item in a table cell and specify horizontal alignment of the table cell to be 'Center', it works for me. Can you please tell me which version of Cognos you are using?

Comment: I'm using congonos 8, I can provide a screenshot of how my report looks in report studio and how it looks in excel if that would be helpful. In excel whenever I start messing with the column sizes the title eventually becomes aligned, so I'm think it can be an issue with that.

Comment: I just think that it wouldn't be correct if I have to size the columns, there must be another way.

Comment: @MichaelYounani Yes, the screen shots will be helpful.

Comment: I added a screenshot, hopefully it is helpful.

Comment: @MichaelYounani Ok, looking at your report design, I see tables nested in table cells in the page header and the design is such that second half section of the heading (Meter Discrepancy Report and next 2 rows) will not align with the table cell containing DeRS title and other 2 rows.  Instead of having title texts (6 rows) in 2 different table structures, you can move all the 6 rows of title in the same table. I cannot attach a screen shot in a comment, so I have added it in my answer.

Answer (score 1):

Take a list object..

unlock the report.
add list header. (note not the page header..)
select the list header and select split cells.
Place a text item in the first list header cell. 
Select all the list header cells and select merge cells.

Now, you can format the merge cells with center and bold.

This will ensure the total number or columns and the list header cells are same.

Run the report and export to excel. This method work in any version of cognos.
--Srrinivas.

Comment: I'm using cognos 8, I cant find list object or a list header.

Comment: I guess all these formatting problems were sorted out in Cognos 10.1

Answer (score 0):

Go to Page Layout, then next to the Gridlines tab is Headings. Click on the expanding arrow right below that.  From within there, go to Header/Footer. Uncheck the boxes that say, "Scale with document" and "Align with page margins". Problem solved.